# Combine multiple datasets based on condition

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataset, conditional-statements

I'm trying to combine two datasets, based on a condition. This would make it easier for me to analyze if all variables would be in 1 dataset. Both datasets have information in the form of variables (columns) as well as an Identifier variable (also a column). This Identifier variable is present in both datasets. Based on this Identifier variable, I want to copy all the specifc information in the cells from one dataset to another. I've already tried to work with a for loop, an if-then-else function and the mutate-funtion.

Below is an example script, the identifier is ''review.id'', the desired result can be found at the bottom. I have basic experience in R, but combining multiple datasets is new for me.

```
review.id <- c(1, 2, 3)
car <- c('Audi','Volkswagen','Skoda')
house.value <- c(143000, 187000, 223000)
df1 <- data.frame(review.id,car,house.value)

View(df1)

review.id <- c(3, 1, 2)
city <- c('Berlin','Sydney','Rio')
kids <- c(3, 0, 1)
df2 <- data.frame(review.id,city,kids)

View(df2)

#Desired Result (df3)
#review.id car         house.value city    kids
#1         Audi        143000      Sydney  0
#2         Volkswagen  187000      Rio     1
#3         Skoda       223000      Berlin  3
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Take a look at the `merge()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` function makes this a piece of cake:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "review.id")

  review.id        car house.value   city kids
1         1       Audi      143000 Sydney    0
2         2 Volkswagen      187000    Rio    1
3         3      Skoda      223000 Berlin    3
```